# plm omitting coefficients while fitting a model

Tags: r, logistic-regression, plm, coefficients, missing-features

I installed and loaded plm, and am using it for classical work about FE, RE etc. models.
I cannot explain, when I fit a model, only some coefficient are worked out, as the others didn't exist. I'm lost.

'''

> model_depr <- plm::plm(depression ~ drug + diagnose, data = depression, type = "within", effect = "individual")

> summary(model_depr)
> '''

The fit is (new is one of the two values of drug):

'''

> Call:
> plm::plm(formula = depression ~ drug + diagnose, data = depression,
> effect = "individual", type = "within")
>
> Balanced Panel: n = 2, T = 2, N = 1020
>
> Residuals:
> Min.  1st Qu.   Median  3rd Qu.     Max.
> -0.76692 -0.49981  0.23308  0.41272  0.67983
>
> ### *Coefficients:
> Estimate Std. Error t-value  Pr(>|t|)
> drugnew 0.179633   0.029736  6.0409 2.147e-09*
>
> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
> Total Sum of Squares:    236.71
> Residual Sum of Squares: 228.51
> R-Squared:      0.034639
> Adj. R-Squared: 0.032741
> F-statistic: 36.4923 on 1 and 1017 DF, p-value: 2.1472e-09
> '''

Comment: Have you checked if they are constant over time? If not it's the "feature" of a FE model that these get omitted.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.